# TypeError: Cannot read property 'onload' of undefined

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to call my JQuery inside a function of VueJS but it does gives me error of TypeError: Cannot read property 'onload' of undefined.

```
    <script>
import show from "C:/Users/vincent.dizon/Desktop/FrontEnd/frontend/public/show";

export default {

    alertVin: function() {
      show.window.onload()
    },
    clickMe: function() {
      alert("YOU CLICKED ME");
    }
  }

</script>
```

Here's my **show.js**

```
   export var myFunction = window.onload = function () {
    const btn = document.querySelector('#show-form');
    const form = document.querySelector('.form');
    const close = document.querySelector('.close-container');

    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        form.classList.add('form-show');
        close.classList.add('x-show');

    })
    close.addEventListener('click', function () {
        close.classList.remove('x-show');
        form.classList.remove('form-show');
    })
}
```

EDIT: UPDATED THE SHOW.JS

Comment: The error means that `show.window` isn't defined.

Comment: Can you add the exports in `frontend/public/show` to the question?

Comment: Hi @Barmar, I updated the question.

Comment: You're not exporting an object, you're just exporting a single function. What do you expect `show.window` to be?

Comment: `show` is just a reference to `myFunction`.

Comment: show.window does my transition to display my form. How can I access myFunction tho?

Comment: You need to do something like `export { window : { onload() { // code } }}`

Comment: With what you've written, you can just do `show()` and it will call `myFunction()`.

Comment: BTW why are you using jquery in vue js you can easily achieve anything in vue that jquery can do ?
|

Comment: you are removing a class on a button click which can easily be handled by a boolean in data property in vuejs and it is easy

Comment: @AKASHPANDEY how?

Comment: @Vin make a data property which will be boolean. and on the button click use click event listener and call a function that will be declared in the methods object in vue and there you can change the boolean and depending on the boolean can apply classes